# How to fix "Amazon MWS Product Detail API from Google Scripts to return product details?"

Tags: amazon-web-services, return, api-design, amazon-mws

I'm Working on a Amazon MWS API to return requested product data into a Google spreadsheet. I'm having some issues trying to return the product details with this and being a novice at coding I'm quite unsure what the issue is with the API itself. Unfortunately so far I can only get a Ping response with a timestamp and that's it. How do I correct this so that the return information is the product data?

function myFunction() {

var parameters =

```
Action= '&Action=GetMatchingProductForId',
AwsAccessKeyID= 'AWSAccessKeyId=xxxxxx',
IdType= '&IdType=ISBN',
ListID= '&IdList.Id.1=9780321601834',
MarketplaceId= '&MarketplaceId=ATVPDKIKX0DER',
Method= 'POST\n',
ResponseGroup= '&ResponseGroup=ItemAttributes',
SellerId= '&SellerId=xxxxxx',
SecretKey= 'xxxxxx', 
Timestamp= Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH%mm%ss'Z'"),
URL= 'https://mws.amazonservices.com',
```

var QueryString =

```
Method+'/Products/2011-10-01\n'+AwsAccessKeyID
+'&Action=GetMatchingProductForId'+IdType+MarketplaceId+ListID
+ResponseGroup+SellerId+'&SignatureMethod=HmacSHA256'
+'&SignatureVersion=2'+'&Timestamp='+Timestamp
+'&Version=2011-10-01';

 var SignedRequest = Utilities.computeHmacSha256Signature(QueryString, SecretKey)
 var Encoded = Utilities.base64Encode(SignedRequest)
```

var Response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(URL, {'muteHttpExceptions': true});
 Logger.log(Response);

The only results I would really like for this is to have this api return the product data before I move onto the next step. Thanks in advance for anyone who takes the time to assist with this issue.

Comment: Hi! It'd be easier for people to help you if you are more specific in your question. Ask a question about a specific issue that you're having, or some error you're not making progress on.

Comment: Oh I apologize about that, the issue is that I cannot get a return with the product details when I run the POST request. I simply get a return from from https://mws.amazonservices.com with a ping and timestamp. I was wondering how to correct this and get the product details to return instead.